# a table view from modal view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am designing application which is completely based on modal view controllers.
now, after  i navigate 4 to 5 screens of my application i want to show the data in tabular format.
All sample applications show table view as the first screen . Please tell me how am i to show the table view later on

My case is: I give the start date and end date to a web service, this web service in return gives me data, which i store it in NSMutableArray.
Now i want to display this data in tabular format

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use a navigation controller. The first view would contain your search fields (the start and end date). When you get the data from the web service, push a table view controller in from the right and show your data. Now the user could use the back button to get back to the view with the start and end date, where she could easily modify the search specs.

Comment: see i am new to iphone application development.I had created a Navigation based application. it created 4 files, delegate files and rootviewcontroller.h & .m files. But i created a new UIView Controller called as loginViewController and kept it as the first screen . now i continued adding many such UIviewControllers.Now i want to display a table, in one of these UIViewControllers